# Follow a circumference path with a constraint

Tags: geometry, optimization, constraints

I have this problem. I tried a lot of options before to post this question.

[image]

By referencing the above, I have an object (the blue point) that is moving towards $a)$ where it finds a value of $n = 40$.

**Edit**: I know the coordinates when the object is on $a)$. Could be a problem where a greedy algorithm could give an approximation of the solution (the points where $n$ is constant)?

The goal is find a path like a circumference in order to keep the value of $n$ constant, like the point $b)$. If the blue dot move towards outside this circumference the value of $n$ could be as the cases $c)$ or $d)$.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand this problem. What is $n$?

Comment: For example could be the temperature of a body, or the power received from a generic source. I called it n as generic parameter/constraint.

Comment: How is $n$ given at other points? Is it a known function $n(x,y)$, table values or measurements?

Comment: It is just a measurement (as I said in the previous comment, it could be a power received from a source or the temperature of this source). I know only that on this particular circumference the value of $n$ is constant.